# Is it ok to usb micro male - micro male for USB device?

Tags: power, pi-zero-w, arduino, usb-power

I am hooking up an arduino micro to my Pi Zero W.

For space, I used a short micro male-male USB cable:
https://www.amazon.ca/CableCreation-Micro-Kindle-Android-Tablet/dp/B01M5GZ3N0

When I use this on startup I can see the pi sends a warning:

`usb 1-1 device descriptor read/64, error -71`

I've read this is a warning about voltage drop occurring. Which you can ignore if you aren't seeing any other problems. I do notice my ssh connection is extremely slow something while using this USB cable.

This does not happen if I use a standard A-micro cable.

Is there a specific recommendation to use A-micro (+ the adapter) or could it just be specific cable I'm using?

Answer (score 0):

USB devices may either be a Host or Peripheral. Most Pi USB (as most computers) act as Host, but a few (including the Pi Zero family) allow OTG which means they can act as either.

The Pi Zero normally acts as Host, but can be configured (in software) to act as Peripheral (e.g Ethernet, serial or mass storage device).

microUSB connectors have a 5th connection (other than the power & data) which can signal this role but when connected to a normal USB type A this has no impact. The cable you referenced is advertised as OTG.

Normal USB involves a Host & a Peripheral. Among other things the Host normally supplies power to the Peripheral but AFAIK the Pi Zero (which has minimal power circuitry - and no published schematic) has no power control.

Attempting to connect 2 devices operating in Host mode is an error.

Without detail of the Arduino micro - how the ID pin is set (and how the Pi Zero W is configured) and what you are attempting to do it is not possible to be more specific.